# Problems loading assets in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm new to the world of app development, but I already have some specific knowledge. But my issue is the following involving libgdx and Android Studio:

When trying to load a texture through the Assets Manager method, the following error occurs:
`

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 593
    Process: br.com.tpgames.dbz, PID: 19495
    com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Asset not loaded: bater_1/goku2.png
        at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.get(AssetManager.java:172)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.get(AssetManager.java:143)
        at br.com.tpgames.dbz.SplashScreen.<init>(SplashScreen.java:53)
```

`

My codes:

main class:

`

```
public class MainClass extends Game {

   public AssetManager manager;


   public void create () {




      setScreen(new SplashScreen (this, manager));

   }


}
```

`

Splash screen
`

```
public class SplashScreen implements Screen {

    private Game game;
    private AssetManager manager;
    private float time = 0;


    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Texture tex;

    long startime;

    public Texture goku;



    public SplashScreen(Game game, AssetManager manager){
        this.game = game;
        this.manager = manager;

        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        tex = new Texture("logo.png");

        startime = TimeUtils.millis();

        manager = new AssetManager();
        for (int i=1;i<=5;i++){
            manager.load("bater_1/"+i+".png",Texture.class);
        }

        boolean load = manager.isLoaded("bater_1/goku1.png");
        Gdx.app.log("Log", String.valueOf(load));


        goku = manager.get("bater_1/goku2.png",Texture.class);




    }


    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        time+=delta;


        if (manager.update() && time >=2){      //Se o tempo for maior que 2 segundos, vai abrir a tela principal
            game.setScreen(new Tela_Principal(game,manager));
        }


        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(tex, (float) (screenx*0.26), (float) (screeny*0.1), (float) (screenx*0.5), (float) (screeny*0.8));

        batch.end();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

`

Constants
`

```
public class Constantes {
    public static int screenx = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    public static int screeny = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
}
```

`

```
Main screen
```

`
public class Tela_Principal implements Screen {

```
private Game game;
private AssetManager manager;
private SpriteBatch batch;

private SplashScreen splashScreen;

// private Texture goku;


public Tela_Principal(Game game, AssetManager manager){
    this.game = game;
    this.manager = manager;

    splashScreen = new SplashScreen(game,manager);


    for (int i=1;i<=5;i++){
        manager.load("bater_1/goku"+i+".png",Texture.class);
    }

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    // goku = manager.get("bater_1/goku1.png",Texture.class);

}


@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {


    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,1,0,0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(splashScreen.goku, (float) (screenx *0.1), (float) (screeny*0.1));
    batch.end();

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
```

}

```
`

I thank you for your help!!
```

Answer (score 0):

`manager.load()` will queue your asset, not immediately load it.
Only when `manager.update()` returns true will the assets be available.

Looks like your problem is in SplashScreen

```
        for (int i=1;i<=5;i++){
            manager.load("bater_1/"+i+".png",Texture.class);
        }
        //not allowed
        goku = manager.get("bater_1/goku2.png",Texture.class);
```

AssetManager is well explained here https://libgdx.com/wiki/managing-your-assets